# HTTP request is hitting "HTTPS:// url" although SSL/HTTPS has been disabled in the server.xml @ Tomcat Apache server

Tags: tomcat, ssl, jvm

I am using Tomcat Apache server (8.5.13),JAVA8 and MSSQL.We have been facing multiple issues bringing up the JVM.To debug better, I have disabled the SSL/HTTPS settings.
Although SSL/HTTPS settings has been disabled @Server.xml,we could still find the HTTP request has been hitting "HTTPS:// url".
Please suggest.

Comment: Please share more information about your structure

Comment: Could you please provide additional information about the details you are looking for ?